# Why Facebook topbar with Position:fixed not doing repaint

Tags: html, css, performance

I'm optimizing my scrolling performance. I use `position:fixed` for my topnav and I noticed that some of the performance issue when I scroll up and down. I use `Show paint rectangles` and it's clearly shown that the nav is being repainted all the time. However, when I look at `Facebook.com` their navbar is using `position:fixed` as well but I don't see their navbar being repainted when I scroll up and down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't check facebook site right now (they have technical works at this moment), but i'm 90% sure that they are applying `backface-visibility: hidden` for navbar (or any other transform-related property). This moves element to dedicated stacking-context layer and prevent's it from continious repainting.

You can check this ugly demo with `Show paint rectangles`- http://codepen.io/suez/pen/fe2e45b3a4b17b723aa8b797178416b7?editors=010 (just comment `backface-visibility` property and see the difference).

Comment: It totally works and the performance is a lot better. But I'm not sure why? If  I put that in would there be any side-affect?

Comment: Nope, no side-effects. You can read dedicated to this problem article here http://benfrain.com/improving-css-performance-fixed-position-elements/

Comment: Actually i forget, there is one side-effect - sub-pixel rendering issues. It's makes some elements sort of blurry. But 95% of time you won't see any difference.